# Passing array to JS as values

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I want to pass an array from PHP to Javascirpt so I just get a list of values - currently I get JSON format - which I know because I'm using JSON_ENCODE I'm just hoping/wondering is there a way to pass it as a simple set of values or to parse it afterwards?

Apologies I'm quite new to this :)

I've tried a few different things from previous answers to similar questions, but none seem to do the trick.

```
<?php 

$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';
$connection_string = 'connectionstringtomysqldatabase';

$connection = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass ); 
$sqlstring = "SELECT FIELD1 FROM TABLE.ITEM where IASOHQ<>0 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $sqlstring);

while ($info = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
$content[] = $info;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var content = <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>;

</script>
```

I want...

```
var content = [68,116,49,57,13,11,46,47,14,79]
```

I get...

```
var content = [{"FIELD1":"68"},{"FIELD1":"116"},{"FIELD1":"49"},{"FIELD1":"57"},{"FIELD1":"13"},{"FIELD1":"11"},{"FIELD1":"46"},{"FIELD1":"47"},{"FIELD1":"14"},{"FIELD1":"79"}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this result because your array is multi-dimensional with associative second level keys i.e. it looks like

```
$content = [['FIELD1' => 68], ['FIELD1' => 116], ..., ['FIELD1' => 79]];
```

This is because [`odbc_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php) returns an associative array for each row. To fix your data format, just change this line:

```
$content[] = $info;
```

to

```
$content[] = $info['FIELD1'];
```

That will give you an array that looks like your desired result of

```
[68,116,49,57,13,11,46,47,14,79]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `'` to make it a value. Change

```
var content = <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>;
```

to

```
var content = '<?php echo json_encode($content); ?>';
var myObject = JSON.parse(content);
```

Iterate over the array then.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this peace of php code. I think that all of the index of array is `FIELD1`

```
...
while ($info = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
$content[] = $info['FIELD1'];
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just
`echo  json_encode(array_values($content))`;
it will work;